# Weird IFRAME issue, page blocks itself from loading

Tags: html, iframe

This is a weird one. I'm using the URL "http://www.craigslist.org/about/" as an example here.

I load up that page in my browser and modify it with Firebug. I add the following line right after the body tag:

```
<iframe src="http://www.craigslist.org/about/" id="frame1" name="frame1" width="100%;" height="200"></iframe>
```

The IFRAME shows as blank! Now when I load https instead of http in the IFRAME it works. At first I thought maybe craigslist doesn't allow itself to be embedded in an IFRAME at all. Then I tried embedding that same IFRAME code on my website and the frame loads as expected.

It's as if they are blocking you from loading the same page within itself!? Anyone ever seen this behavior before?

**UPDATE:**

This problem appears to be related to my browser. (Firefox 21) When I try to load any IFRAME that has the same exact URL as the parent frame it fails??

Comment: If you are using `https` then everything within that document must be the same. What's the URL of the page it's being embedded into?

Comment: Try embedding http://www.craigslist.org/about/ into -> http://www.craigslist.org/about/ both HTTP

Comment: Not really sure what the issue is here, or what relevance this question has to any code you're editing, other than the temporary code in your browser. Adding that `<iframe />` below the body of the site in Firebug works fine.

Comment: You're able to embed "http://www.craigslist.org/about/" as an IFRAME into "http://www.craigslist.org/about/" ??? I'm using Firefox 21 maybe that's causing the bug?

Comment: I am encountering the same problem -- just wondering if you found a solution to this?